# VSCode Flutter Installation Problem: Failed to initialize Flutter: Process exited with code 126

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

After installing Flutter from the extensions market in VScode, a message pops up at the bottom: "Failed to initialize Flutter: Process exited with code 126."
Things I tried:

- Looked into the extension's github repo and searched 126, and there were no results.
- Looked into the code in Flutter github, and I wasn't able to find such an exit code.
- Looked into the vscode github repo and I wasn't able to find an instance of "process exited with code"

Comment: Can you try running enabling [the extension log](https://dartcode.org/docs/logging/#extension) and reproducing the issue, then see what's in the log? If you attach it to an issue at https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code I'm less likely to miss it than a response here. Thanks!

Comment: I've also filed https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/2958 about making it easier to get at the log file when this happens.

Comment: @DannyTuppeny sorry if this is obvious but how do I set dart.extensionLogFile to a file path, for example /Users/dantup/Desktop/extension.txt?

Comment: you can run the **Peferences: Open Settings** command from the VS Code command palette. You can either enter it in the JSON view, or search for "extension log" in the search box using the settings UI.

Comment: Updating VS CODE has solved this issue